# WHAT AM I DOING WRONG i get the error :HiScoresList.sort(key=(BestScore)) TypeError: BestScore() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Tags: python

i am trying to sort this external file but i keep getting this error and have no idea how to fix it. my code is:

```py
with open('Leaderboard.txt', "r") as fin:
    HiScores = fin.read().splitlines()
    HiScoresList = []
    for score in HiScores:
        namescore = score.split(', ')
        score = str(score.strip())
        HiScoresList.append((namescore))

        # Look at two score entries, and compare which score is larger
        def BestScore(a, b):
            return cmp(b[1], a[1])
        HiScoresList.sort(key=(BestScore))

        for HiScore in HiScoresList:
            print(HiScore)
```

and this is the error

```
  HiScoresList.sort(key=(BestScore))
```

> TypeError: BestScore() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

im pretty new to python so if you could explain how to fix this in your response i would appreciate it

Comment: Please don't SHOUT. If you need to emphasize something in your question body you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). And your title will be automatically styled as a title.

Comment: Furthermore, your title should concisely summarize your question. "What am I doing wrong", even when not in all caps, is a bad title. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `key-argument` specifies a function of **one argument** that is used to extract a comparison key from each element

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort

Answer (score 0):

`.sort()` expects a key that takes *one* argument. It feeds each element in `HiScoresList` into that key function, and uses the output. Even if each element of `HiScoresList` is a tuple, that element still gets passed as only *one* argument.

The easy fix to make the error go away is to change `BestScore()` to take a 2-tuple as an argument, instead of two entire arguments:

```
def BestScore(tup):
    a, b = tup
    return cmp(b[1], a[1])
```

Comment: The OP got confused between the "key" function and a comparison function, but at least it's implementation is valid for a comparison function. Your answer is still confusing the two concept but your "easy fix" is totally invalid either as a comparison function or as a key one.

Answer (score 0):

As documented, the `key` argument to `list.sort()` isn't a comparison function of two elements but a function taking one single element and returning the value to be used for sorting this element.

In your case, assuming your `HiScoreList` is a list of `(name, score)` tuples and you want to sort on the score, the `key` function will receive a `(name, score)` tuple and should return the `score` part, ie:

```
def BestScore(namescore):
    return namescore[1]
```

now since you kept your scores as strings, this will still not work as expected (it would sort `"12"` before `"2"` - those are strings so they are sorted on lexicographical order). You can either change `BestScore` to take care of this:

```
def BestScore(namescore):
    return int(namescore[1])
```

or turn the scores into it right from the start (which is what I would do):

```
hiscores = []

with open('Leaderboard.txt', "r") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue

        name, score = line.split(",", 1)
        hiscores.append((name.strip(), int(score)))

hiscores.sort(key=lambda namescore: namescore[1])
print(hiscores)
```

Comment: thanks a lot youve really helped me out but im trying to print the list in order of highest score to lowest (at the moment it prints in order of lowest to highest) and only the 5 highest scores need to be printed so if you know how i would really appreciate it

Comment: @Deadguy318 for the first point, read the options for `list.sort()`. For the second one, look up the doc for list slicing. [All of this is documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)